# Bootstrap likelihood ratio test using PoLCA models in R?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a scale of 10 Likert variables (1-5) completed by 300 individuals:

```
###set seed
set.seed(421)

###create random likert variables, N = 300
var1 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var3 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var4 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var5 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var6 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var7 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var8 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var9 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)
var10 <- sample(1:5, 300, replace = T)

df = data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5,
                  var6, var7, var8, var9, var10))
```

Using the [PoLCA package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poLCA/poLCA.pdf), I model the data using different numbers of classes like so:

```
###define group of functions to use
all_v <- cbind(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10) ~ 1

###set seed
set.seed(421)

###1 class
LCA_1 <- poLCA(all_v, data = df, nclass=1, maxiter=10000, 
                       graphs=T, tol=1e-10, na.rm=TRUE, probs.start=NULL, 
                       nrep=500, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)

###2 classes
LCA_2 <- poLCA(all_v, data = df, nclass=2, maxiter=10000, 
                       graphs=T, tol=1e-10, na.rm=TRUE, probs.start=NULL, 
                       nrep=500, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)

###3 classes
LCA_3 <- poLCA(all_v, data = df, nclass=3, maxiter=10000, 
                       graphs=T, tol=1e-10, na.rm=TRUE, probs.start=NULL, 
                       nrep=500, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)
```

When evaluating fit, I know I can use the fit stats provided by PoLCA (e.g., BIC, AIC), and I can conduct a normal likelihood ratio test using the following:

```
###pick random LL's for each class of model
logLik_1 <- -2658.805
logLik_2 <- -2658.055
logLik_3 <- -4668.640

###conduct example LL test using these values
teststat <- -2 * (logLik_1 - logLik_2)
pchisq(teststat, df = 5, lower.tail = F)
```

From the literature I've seen, though, it's more desirable these days to run a bootstrap likelihood ratio test. I've tried to use the boot.LR function from the [R mirt package](https://rdrr.io/cran/mirt/), but I get this error:

```
Error in boot.LR(LCA_1, LCA_2) : is(mod, "SingleGroupClass") is not TRUE
```

Any suggestions? Your time/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that if you want to use `boot.LR` function, in a basic form `boot.LR(mod, mod2, R = 1000)`, `mod1` and `mod2` object need to obtain from `mirt()` function.
In `boot.LR` function, there is `is(mod, "SingleGroupClass")` condition and `"SingleGroupClass"` defines the object returned from `mirt` when model is exploratory. ( ["SingleGroupClass"](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mirt/versions/1.33.2/topics/SingleGroupClass-class) , [boot.LR source](https://rdrr.io/cran/mirt/src/R/boot.LR.R))